# What metric should I be gathering to allow making predictions about how dependent two variables are?

Tags: dataset

I currently have a large set of tuples (a,b) and have various statistics gathered independently about the set of a's and b's. Including a histogram for each. That lets me predict approximately how many tuples have a=x or b=y.

However it is often the case that a and b are not independent and a=x && b=y is either much smaller or much larger than the product of the two fractions.

I need a metric that can be gathered about  that will allow me to estimate the approximate number of tuples where a=x && b=y. That metric should be a constant size independent of the number of tuples (like a histogram) and be possible to generate from a sample of the tuples (like a histogram:).

Failing that it might be helpful to just know to what degree the product of the fractions is unreliable. That is the degree two which the two variables fail to be independent.

Incidentally the variables are not necessarily integers or reals. Ideally it should be possible to calculate it purely using comparisons.

I feel like this is some standard statistics problem and I'm just missing the right terminology to find it.